# Adding a timestamp to "output" window for TFS pulls using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

In the "Output" window in Visual Studio, under "Source Control - Team Foundation" for TFS, you can see the list of files that you pull down when you execute a "Get Latest" request.

Is there any way to add a timestamp to the file names to alert you as to when you retrieved that file?

what I see:

```
Replacing: C:\MyDir\myFile.c
```

what I would like to see:

```
Replacing: C:\MyDir\myFile.c 2018-02-23 14:48:09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default way to show the timestamp in `Source Control -- Team Foundation` windows pane. You could check the timestamp for the file in the Source Control Explorer:

[image]

Otherwise, you could consider creating and managing your own custom panes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-output-window